# Distinguishing between regular and one-time invocations in Puppet code

Tags: puppet

Can a Puppet script find out whether it was invoked as part of regular configuration run, i.e. a Puppet agent applying configurations at regular intervals (i.e. `puppet agent`), or because of one-time actions (e.g. `puppet agent -t`, `puppet apply`)?

Comment: You would likely need to make use of an intrinsic that differs between a master and masterless environment, such as `$environment`, for agent versus apply. As for agent one time versus agent daemonized, very likely not.

Comment: Note also that whether `$environment` in particular is useful for making such a distinction depends on details of your Puppet configurations on target node and puppetmaster.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is this new behavior in puppet 5 where sometimes in masterless the environment intrinsic is set to "root" instead of "production", but I have not noticed what is triggering that behavior. Maybe you have seen the relevant source code or read why that occurs. It would probably be helpful for this.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the behavior you describe is unfamiliar to me, and I don't find any indication in the current docs that it should be expected, except to the extent that Puppet could be configured in such a way as to produce it.  If you see the environment defaulting to "root" without that being explicitly configured, then that constitutes an issue that should be reported, albeit perhaps only against the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this yet in practice, but the following may allow a way forward:

Settings on the [command line](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/config_about_settings.html#settings-on-the-command-line) (such as `--test`) are also available as Puppet [master variables](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html#puppet-master-variables) (such as `$settings::test`).

The Puppet master variable `$servername` identifies the Puppet master for `puppet agent` runs and is (perhaps) `undef` for `puppet apply` runs.

Hence a recipe for an overall solution may look as follows:

```
$onetime = $settings::test or $settings::onetime or ($servername == undef)
```